# AngularJS Two-Way-Binding: How can i prevent updating model on error?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am calling a webservice which returns data in JSON format. I store this into a variable called **myrecipes** and show these through rg-repeat in a grid. This works fine! I have bound the database field to the checkbox through ng-model. This works, too. Now my requirement:

I could call a webservice function to update the current item in the database through ng-change. When the call is successfull the model gets updated and the value in the database is updated, too. Everything fine!

BUT what if something goes wrong when i try to update the value in the database through the webservice? The model (the local data) is getting updated but the value in the database not! That may not happen! How can i prevent this? How could i perhaps catch a single item which was triggered through the ng-change and set the value in the model back to the previous value?

regards
bog

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="item.someProperty"data-ng-click="someFunction($index)"/>{{item.description}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

When the user click on checkbox, the funcion will be called, and pass the index of item, so you can get the index of object in items array, and you can do something with that

Comment: But wouldnt be model get updated on item change too, due to two-way-binding via ng-model ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, in this case you can do a new request and fill only the item, when something goes wrong.

Like:

`$http(urlRequest, {params}).success(function(data){
  items[index] = data;
//data is the object with the real value
});`

Comment: i think i should query again for the updated item in the db and this one should be written back to to he local data?

Comment: Yes. **OR** save the item in another object and if something goes wrong you copy the "item copy" to original item.
Like:

`$scope.copiedItem = {properties};
 $scope.functionCheckbox = function(index){
    angular.copy($scope.items[index], $scope.copiedItem);
    $http.post(url, {params}).success(function(data){
       $scope.items[index] = data;
    }).error(function(){
        angular.copy($scope.copiedItem, $scope.items[index]);
    })
}`